# Ignore a dependency during R CMD check

Tags: r, github-actions, r-package

I have a package that I developed to enable my team (and perhaps other interested users) to install and use a particular R package ([RQDA](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQDA/index.html)) that was archived on CRAN. I have hosted [this package](https://github.com/BroVic/RQDAassist) on GitHub and am trying to set up GitHub Actions so that I have a CI workflow in place.

Whenever I run `R CMD check` locally everything is fine, but when I push to GitHub the build fails. This is because, by default, Actions tries to install that same (archived) package. Expectedly, this fails.

[image: build failure]

So, my question is this: is there a way I can disable the `check` for a specific package dependency? There are no plans to **ever** send this package to CRAN, so I am happy to bypass their package policy in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

2 possible ways:

- Upload the source for RQDA to a Github repo, or other publicly accessible location, and put a `Remotes:` line in your DESCRIPTION file
- Save the package to cloud storage, eg an S3 bucket or Azure storage container, and download it from there as a separate workflow step prior to checking

Comment: Although I was able to solve it differently, your answer actually gives me a whole new perspective. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to deal with the problem:

The changes made were entirely in the workflow file at `./.github/workflows/`. One of the jobs there is for installing R package dependencies for the project:

```
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
      remotes::install_cran("rcmdcheck")
    shell: Rscript {0}
```

The first thing I did was to change the `dependencies` argument to `NA` so that only packages listed in `Depends` and `Imports` are installed. (The RQDA dependency that was giving me trouble is under `Suggests`).

There was still an error but this time with some guidance that involved going to the job `Check` and setting the environment variable  `_R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_` to `false`.

The `check` now works as expected.